# Sending a closure (which returns a struct with a trait) to a thread leads to sized error

Tags: multithreading, rust, closures

I'm trying to send a closure which will generate a structure to a thread, however when I try to do it I get a Sized error. I understand the error (the size is indeed not known at compile time), however adding Boxes and other such tricks does not seem to solve it.

I've tried to look into how to implement the Sized trait, however it seems to be quite special and honestly above my understanding.

I've written a minimal reproducible example:

```
use std::thread;

trait DataProcess {
    fn start(&self);
    fn run(&self);
    fn stop(&self);
}

struct SomeDP {
    name: String,
}

impl DataProcess for SomeDP {
    fn start(&self) {
        println!("Started");
    }
    fn run(&self) {
        println!("Running");
    }
    fn stop(&self) {
        println!("Stopped");
    }
}

fn thread_maker(builder: Box<dyn Fn() -> (dyn DataProcess + Send)>) {
    let thread_builder = thread::Builder::new();
    let handle = thread_builder.spawn(move || {
        let dp = builder();
        dp.start();
    });
}

fn main() {
    let dp_builder = || SomeDP {
        name: "nice".to_string(),
    };
    thread_maker(Box::new(dp_builder));
}
```

Which you can also find on the playground [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=31081330a7601ef8bba2a2822ce9ef5a)

Comment: does this work? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1eb470e22832a3a410943cddc5d2e257

Comment: Looks good! I'm going to check it in my code and see if I didn't forget something in the minimal reproducible example, be right back

Comment: There seems to be more errors now, I'm going to try and debug and come back if the issue is still relevant. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Neeraj, you did answer this threads question indeed, I'm now having other problems but those are far enough that they would require another question. Thank you for your help and feel free to write the answer if you want me to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```rust
use std::thread;

trait DataProcess{
    fn start(&self);
    fn run(&self);
    fn stop(&self);
}

struct SomeDP{
    name: String
}

impl DataProcess for SomeDP{
    fn start(&self){println!("Started");}
    fn run(&self){println!("Running");}
    fn stop(&self){println!("Stopped");}
}

fn thread_maker<F>(builder: F)
where
    F: Fn() -> Box<dyn DataProcess>,
    F: Send + 'static {
    let thread_builder = thread::Builder::new();
    let handle = thread_builder.spawn(
        move ||{
            let dp = builder();
            dp.start();
        }
    );
}

fn main(){
    let dp_builder = || -> Box<dyn DataProcess> {
        Box::new(SomeDP{name: "nice".to_string()})
    };
    thread_maker(dp_builder);
}
```